# what is a multiple precision integer?

Tags: math

"A is a multiple precision n-bit integer represented in radix r"
What does this statement mean?
In particular, what does A being a multiple precision n-bit integer mean?
Please help.
Thank you

Comment: I think the term is a misnomer - the "precision" doesn't vary, only the *size* of the representation changes. The term "precision" is probably used because we refer to 32-bit float representations as single precision and 64-bit float representations as double precision - but in that context, the term "precision" actually makes a lot of sense, as 64-bit floats are capable of much more precision than 32-bit floats.

Comment: BTW - I don't think I've ever heard the term 'multiple precision n-bit integer', but if it exists, the only sane interpretation is a variable-bit-width integer built from (a resizable array of) as many n-bit chunks (typically register-width unsigned integer values) as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very difficult to say without any context.

But if I had to guess, I'd say it's probably referring to [*arbitrary-precision arithmetic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).  i.e. it's a type with no constraints on storage (and therefore no constraints on number of digits).

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the usual interpretation. Some google-fu provides an example: "A multiple-precision unsigned integer is a variable of the class mpuint: mpuint x(n);. Here n is the number of 16-bit unsigned integers used to represent x." http://www.efgh.com/software/mpuint.htm

Answer (score 12):

Let me answer my own question

if the processor is an X bit processor, any integer number that can be represented with in X bits ( ie, 0 to ((2^X)-1) for unsigned int's) it is a single precision numbers. If the integer needs to be represented using more than X bits, it is a multiple precision number. Usually any number is represented using bits that are a multiple of X, since an X bit processor has registers X bits wide, and if a number requires , for eg, 1 bit more than X, it still needs two X bit registers to be stored (hence such a number would be double precision)

Another example, a floating point number in C requires 4 bytes space. So something like

float x;

is a single precision floating point number

double x; requires twice the space of float, hence it is a double precision floating point number

(And if you believe this is wrong please leave your suggestions in the comments)

Comment: +1 This definition matches the usage I've encountered. An MPI isn't a type with *no* constraints on storage, but one where the storage is larger than one machine word.